# Is there a need of SMPP Server if I want to send sms uding jsmpp?

Tags: smpp, jsmpp

If I get the connection details from a service provider who needs the ESME to talk to SMSC in SMPP, do I need to have my own SSMP server running on my machine too? Or can I just build a client to connect to SMSC And send SMS? I am using JSMPP to send sms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send SMS through a provider, all you need an ESME which will connect to the SMSC of the provider. This is independent of SMPP library you are using.

If you want to **test** your ESME and the SMS(s) the ESME is sending, you would be better of with your own SMSC.

Comment: Yes I want to send SMS through a provider, are you saying that I will not JSMPP in that case? Then what will I need?

Comment: To talk to the SMSC we need to use the protocol that the pprovidr supports, either HTTP or SSMP. have I got it all wrong?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Technically - (1) SMSC and ESME communicate over SMPP protocol, (2) HTTP client and web servers communicate over HTTP protocol.

Comment: Right so all the service providers use only SSMP to talk to SMSC? And they do use SSMP, how can the ESME be independent of SSMP library that am using?

Comment: Because, SMPP is a protocol. SMSC does not care which library you use to create your ESME, as long as that ESME speaks SMPP... I think you wanted to type SMPP, not SSMP.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Sorry, I meant SMPP. Yes, now I know what you meant. Also, i have one more question  regarding setting up my own SMSC, if I successfully set it up can I realistically get the sms sent by the ESME on my mobile station?? I can't see how it can without the actual network getting involved.

Comment: When your ESME is connected to your SMSC, your goal is to test; this won't get SMS delivered to your MS. Only a true SMSC (which a provider will offer to you) is capable of sending messages to MS.

Comment: Thought so, thank you so much for clearifying my doubts mate.